# findQ in mongooseQ

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, promise

Want to assign to the variable x value found result, how to do it. Thank you.

```
var x;
someModel.findQ({"name":"John"}.then(function(result){
    result// here i have my object, how i can make this in var x ?
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't put it in `var x`*, that's how JavaScript concurrency works. See [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call/16825593#16825593) on a broader take on the topic.

```
someModel.findQ({"name":"John"}.then(function(result){
    // use result here
});
```

You don't have to nest though, since promises chain

```
someModel.findQ({"name":"John"}.then(function(result){
    // use result here
    return someOtherModel.findQ({"name" : result.name }); 
}).then(function(obj){
    // you can access the return result of someOtherModel here
});
```

<sup>* unless you're willing to try experimental features like generators that aren't in node stable yet.</sup>